# PHP JSON Encode: Formatting

Tags: php, json

I wanted to have an json output format like this

```
{
    "data":
    [
        ["FAMILY: Isopropyl Alcohol 250ml","32.34"],
        ["AMBROXOL Expel 6mg-mL 15ML Drops","75.04"]

    ]

}
```

However, it is showing differently as wanted. The first items keeps on replicated.
The result is:

```
{
"data":
[
    ["FAMILY: Isopropyl Alcohol 250ml","32.34"],
    ["FAMILY: Isopropyl Alcohol 250ml","32.34","AMBROXOL Expel 6mg-mL 15ML Drops","75.04"]

]

}
```

This is my php code:

```
foreach ($this->cases_model->test() as $row)        {

                $new_row[]=$row['name'];
                $new_row[]=$row['dp'];
                $row_set['data'][] = $new_row; //build an array
          }

      echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$new_row` is not cleared, so it holds the data of the previous iteration. So, change your `foreach` to:

```
foreach ($this->cases_model->test() as $row){
    $new_row = []; //Reset the array for every loop
    $new_row[]=$row['name'];
    $new_row[]=$row['dp'];
    $row_set['data'][] = $new_row; //build an array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($this->cases_model->test() as $row)        {

    $new_row[]=$row['name'];
    $new_row[]=$row['dp'];
    $row_set['data'][] = $new_row; //build an array
    $new_row = NULL;     
}
```